# Can I embed Swing components in Jogl?

Tags: java, swing, swt, jogl

I need to build a complex graphical editor for Eclipse. I don't like draw2d, and I find it weak for my requirements compared to java2d.

I can use Swing on SWT, so I'll probably be using Swing to build my editor. However, I am keen to implement some fancy stuff which would require mixing bezier curves, shapes etc with Swing components. For example, imagine a swing table connected to another swing component with a bezier spline. I would like to create hovering controls positioned relative to existing ones: imagine a custom swing component appearing in response to a mouse over, when the mouse is on the table I've mentioned. Visual studio's hovering debug windows or Word 2010's text properties widget appearing when you select a text would be examples similar to what I want.

On top of all of this, I'd like to animate, fade in, fade out built in swing widgets and custom components, such as curves etc.

JavaFX allowed using Swing components in its version 1.X, which would give me pretty much all that I want, but they threw away this functionality in 2.x. You can only embed JavaFX in swing or swt now, not the other way around.

After searching for options, I've come across Jogl, which claims integration with AWT and Swing widgets, though I can't really understand what that means. Can I draw all my curves, widgets etc on a GLJpanel, animate these with openGL, and add implement the kind of functionality I've described above? This is all supposed to happen in Eclipse, so I'm supposed to embed this in SWT.

Am I looking for trouble here, or is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the the timingframework (http://java.net/projects/timingframework) for all animations (fade in etc.)
For the cool popup controls you can use the JXLayer / JLayer (http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/ for JDK 6 Support)